What is the proper way to configure proxy_pass in nginx webserver
I am facing difficulties in configuring proxy_pass in nginx setup.
I have a reactjs app and now I am deploying it now at https://free.lmtools.com site.
All the reactjs links working fine.
All the nodejs (express) links not working.
My nginx config file looks as below.
server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate some.path.cert.file; 
    ssl_certificate_key some.path.key.file;

    root some.root.path;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name free.lmtools.com www.free.lmtools.com;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        #proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
}  

If I uncomment proxy_pass then I can not even access the reactjs links.
On experimental basis I added below config
location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/auth;
}

I see for /auth link, nginx server can forward auth request to nodejs/express server and authentication goes through.
Now my question is how many such config blocks I can add as I have 100+ such apis at backend nodejs/express server. Some starts with /auth, some with /component, some with /api etc. Again I have links like /component/token1/token2/token3 etc.
Given this scenario whats the best approach. Should I rewrite the code and all the links of nodejs/express server should be started with like something /api/..., and then have a single block as below
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api;
}

This will not work as links will be like /api/token1/token2/... , how to write such config blocks in a generic way.

Just my opinion but I would change the frontend requests to use the /api prefix and have nginx forward only those requests. You don't need to change the backend though since you can also have nginx trim the /api prefix, eg /api/foo/bar is forwarded to http://localhost:8000/foo/bar

Basically in react code where all I am doing axios.post('/fetch/token1/token2,  I need to change to  axios.post('/api/fetch/token1/token2. And in nginx config, I need to add a location config like location /api { ....  Now my question is how can I write the location block in a generic way so that token1, token2 etc are preserved in request uri while forwarding the request to port 8000 where my express server running.

location /api/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
This helped me to resolve the issue. Whereever I was doing axio.post('/someuri/token1 changed to axio.post('/api/someuri/token1

Your question is also have your answer. Or you can config proxy_pass for all routers then use router in express to response to index.html and css, js...
Edited Answer:
nginx:
server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate some.path.cert.file; 
    ssl_certificate_key some.path.key.file;

#    root some.root.path;
#    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name free.lmtools.com www.free.lmtools.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}  

In nodejs (express)
app.use("/", express.static("some.root.path"));


Please provide more information or an example. I did not understand much from your answer.
